# CKEditor: Disable the textarea and not the buttons

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Can anyone tell me how to disable the textarea/content area without disabling the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you'd like to accomplish, so perhaps you could explain that in a bit more detail.

In any case, you can make CKEditor read-only by using the [setReadOnly()](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setReadOnly) method. This will disable both the toolbar and the content area. Making just the content area disabled with buttons enabled would create a really confusing UX, with the users not really understanding what's going on so perhaps you can re-think your idea?

You can see the [Read-only Mode demo](https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/readonly.html) and read more about this feature in the [Read-Only Mode documentation](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_readonly).

Comment: I have a image to explain my requirement. Please view the link below https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hJz2j5e0TpOKONj7b86vLCZSnAPNr6F1/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below hack but please note that you will only be able to style existing content but you won't be able to insert anything (e.g. you won't insert table but you will be able to bold or link your text).

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    language: 'en',
    on : {
        contentDom : function( event ) {
            CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.getBody().setAttribute( 'contenteditable', false );
        }
    }   
});
```